# Create dummy variables from all categorical variables in a dataframe

Tags: r, tidyverse, one-hot-encoding

I need to one-encode all categorical columns in a dataframe. I found something like this:

```
one_hot <- function(df, key) {
  key_col <- dplyr::select_var(names(df), !! rlang::enquo(key))
  df <- df %>% mutate(.value = 1, .id = seq(n()))
  df <- df %>% tidyr::spread_(key_col, ".value", fill = 0, sep = "_") %>% 
  select(-.id)
}
```

but I can't figure out how to apply it for all categorical columns.

```
keys <- select_if(data, is.character)[-c(1:2)]
tmp <- map(keys, function(names) reduce(data, ~one_hot(.x, keys)))
```

throws next error

> Error: `var` must evaluate to a single number or a column name, not a list

upd:

```
customers <- data.frame(
  id=c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50),
  gender=c('male', 'female', 'female', 'male', 'female'),
  mood=c('happy', 'sad', 'happy', 'sad','happy'),
  outcome=c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0))
customers
```

after encoding

```
  id gender.female gender.male mood.happy mood.sad outcome
1 10             0           1          1        0       1
2 20             1           0          0        1       1
3 30             1           0          1        0       0
4 40             0           1          0        1       0
5 50             1           0          1        0       0
```

Comment: Could you provide a small example data frame and what you want the result to look like for that data frame? This will help folks answer your question.

Comment: Done. But imagine that I have much more categorical features

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also one-liner with `fastDummies` package.

```
fastDummies::dummy_cols(customers)

  id gender  mood outcome gender_male gender_female mood_happy mood_sad
1 10   male happy       1           1             0          1        0
2 20 female   sad       1           0             1          0        1
3 30 female happy       0           0             1          1        0
4 40   male   sad       0           1             0          0        1
5 50 female happy       0           0             1          1        0
```

Answer (score 4):

Using the `dummies` package:

```
library(dummies)
dummy.data.frame(customers)

  id genderfemale gendermale moodhappy moodsad outcome
1 10            0          1         1       0       1
2 20            1          0         0       1       1
3 30            1          0         1       0       0
4 40            0          1         0       1       0
5 50            1          0         1       0       0
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach using the `recipes` package.

```
library(dplyr)
library(recipes)

# Declares which variables are the predictors
recipe(formula = outcome ~ .,
       data = customers) %>% 
# Declare that one-hot encoding will be applied to all nominal variables
step_dummy(all_nominal(),
           one_hot = TRUE) %>% 
# Based on the previous declarations, apply transformations to the data
# and return the resulting data frame
prep() %>% 
juice()
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. `recipes::step_dummy` offers a lot of flexibility to easily call dummies on subsets of variables in a more obvious way than other approaches.

Answer (score 0):

One-liner with `mltools` and `data.table`:

```
one_hot(as.data.table(customers))

   id gender_female gender_male mood_happy mood_sad outcome
1: 10             0           1          1        0       1
2: 20             1           0          0        1       1
3: 30             1           0          1        0       0
4: 40             0           1          0        1       0
5: 50             1           0          1        0       0
```

It one-hots all factor variables and has some nice features built in on how to handle NA`s and unused factor levels.